# Play- 1.2.4 xss automatic escape issue

Tags: xss, playframework-1.x

In the URL(http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.1.1/security#xss), it has been mentioned as that the after play version 1.0.1 release, the strings are automatically escaped, however such is not the case in Play 1.2.4 which is my current version.
Please suggest what possibly could be incorrect here?

Comment: "however such is not the case" < are you sure? Show us what you're trying to do, what you expect and what you get instead. Till then, nobody can really help you out here.

Answer (score 0):

I met same thing in past, but that situation only appear on tag.

I mean, when using on template, it automatically escape HTML (for preventing XSS), but in tags it does not. And I must declare `${someVar?.escape().raw()}` in all tags.